# Transfer OpenCV image from Python to JavaScript using Django Channels

Tags: javascript, python, image-processing, base64, django-channels

I am working on a Django app with channels. I am sending strings from Python to JS successfully. What I want next is to send image processed using opencv and stream in browser using django channels.

How and in what format do I send image from Python to JS such that it can be displayed in a part of a browser with other elements?

I tried converting opencv image into base64 but can't figure out how to use that string in JavaScript.